# Why the objects I make in a loop become the same?

Tags: python, oop, list-comprehension

Here is my program:

some class:

```
class Employee (object):

    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, id, name, password):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.password = password

    @classmethod
    def toString(self):
        return(self.id + ": " + self.name + " " + self.password)
```

Than I try to read some data from a JSON:

```
import os
import json

if os.name == 'nt':
    path = r'Storage\employee.json'
else:
    path  = r'Storage/employee.json'

from employee import Employee

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        json_list = json.loads(file.read())
        list = [Employee(item['id'], item['name'], item['password']) for item in json_list]
        for elemt in list:
            print (elemt.toString())
```

I can read the data without any problem but when I try to make a list of Employee with it. The list become repetitions of the last object.

Comment: Stop putting `classmethod` on every method. It doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: `__init__` is **not** a `@classmethod` and by `toString` (which is not a classmethodas well) you probably mean `__str__`

Comment: In this case, neither is `toString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotating a method with `@classmethod` means it belongs to the **class**, not to a specific instance. Remove those decorators from both methods in your `Employee` class and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

`classmethod` does not work the way you think it does in this case. Rather, you can use the Pythonic `__repr__` method:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, *args):
       self.__dict__ = dict(zip(['id', 'name', 'password'], args))
    def __repr__(self):
       return "{id}:{name} {password}".format(**self.__dict__)

list = [Employee(item['id'], item['name'], item['password']) for item in json_list]
```